# how do you get rid of the picture title bar when using action bar?

Tags: android

Hi I was just wondering if anyone could help me get rid of this bar with the picture above the singleplayer/multiplayer/friends tabs

[image]

Here is what I tried :

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
```

I couldnt find any other option that would take care of this case... Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Add this:

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

A quick test did, in fact hide the logo.

Let me see if I can also find the `styles.xml` version of it so you wont have to code it in every `Activity` / `Fragment`. I know I have it in one of my apps somewhere.

**EDIT:** Found the `styles.xml` too. This is useful if you need to hide the App Logo in every `Activity` / `Fragment` that will inherit the ActionBar style. If it is a few select `Activities` / `Fragments`, the Java code is good.

Add this to your `ActionBar` style:

```
<item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. I am still alittle confused where to put that style thing. Where is the ActionBar style

Comment: Do you know how to get rid of that entire bar that holds that pictures instead of just the picture itself? THanks

Comment: @James: If you are looking to hide the entire `ActionBar`, then refer to Alex's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowHomeEnabled%28boolean%29

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:
        getActionBar().hide();
and if you got deeper knowledge of android you can fix it in your res/values/styles file:
if you are developing for android v14 and more:

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"></style>
<style name="YourThemeBlack" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"></style>
```

then go to the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/YourTheme" > or YourBlackTheme
    <activity....
```

if you wanna accept the theme for only one activity:

```
   <activity
        android:name="ua.bloxy.buildinghouse.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/YourTheme" >
```

So that to hide logo , just set up a transparent image...
for example create a .png image without background or you are able to create a transparent drawable in the android:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#00000000" />

</shape>
```

then in android manifest

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
```

and here you go:
[image]

Comment: The OP does not want to the hide the **entire** `ActionBar`. He just want's to hide the App Logo on the `ActionBar`.

Comment: Will this method still keep my tabs that use the actionbar?

Comment: I think tabs are kinda like a widget. Cause in old android versions tabs were the widget element. And using this method you are olny hide an action bar, not the tabs. In order to hide the tabs you got to set actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);